# Misplaced venue in Foursquare

Tags: foursquare

I've seen some venues away from they real place on Foursquare. (2-3 km away actually) Is there a way to correct these positions without claiming the venues? (Preferably from the web interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search I've found my answer.

[Foursquare support says](http://foursquare.zendesk.com/entries/211235-how-do-i-edit-a-venue) that it is possible to edit venues on the web but to do that you have to be a superuser, the mayor or the one who added that venue.

Answer (score 1):

From here: http://support.foursquare.com/entries/225585-how-do-i-report-duplicate-venues

> You can flag a venue as closed,
>   duplicate, or as having an incorrect
>   address from the app. On the Android
>   click on menu and then Edit Venue when
>   on a venue page. On the iPhone, click
>   on the square with the arrow in the
>   upper right corner to flag a venue as
>   a duplicate. A superuser will approve
>   your suggested merge. If you're a
>   superuser, you can suggest merges from
>   the Edit Venue view, and go through
>   the merge queue for your town.
>
> You can also report duplicate venues
>   on your computer at
>   http://getsatisfaction.com/foursquare
>   where our superusers will help you
>   out!

Comment: I was looking for a preferably web based answer which is platform independent. (Sorry, question edited) However I've not found an "Edit Venue" in the Android applications menu for venue pages (Maybe I'm lame or it's well hidden.) and I don't have any iPhones.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only web-based solution is the forum on getsatisfaction.com. In my experience issues such as this aren't handled in a timely fashion, however.