# How do I merge venues on Foursquare?

Tags: foursquare

I am a mayor of a place I know to be a duplicate, but I still can't merge it. It says this on the edit venue page:

> Super User editing tools
>
> To help keep foursquare venues accurate, we have a few tools for trusted users that let them edit, update, or merge venues. Thanks for helping to improve foursquare venue listings!

but there is no option to merge, only to edit the venue address?

Comment: Closely related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/8623/misplaced-venue-in-foursquare

Comment: That question is not closely related. I am both the mayor and a superuser, yet the option is not there.

Comment: are you sure you are a superuser selected by the 4sq staff? Or do you just have the Super User badge? Two different things...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A mayor can only edit the information for a venue. To merge venues, you must be a [Superuser](http://aboutfoursquare.com/faq-what-is-a-superuser/) who has been selected by the Foursquare staff.

Comment: Yeah I had the superuser badge. Apparently that makes me a level 1 super user. But there are also levels 2 & 3, that are selected by staff. Its kinda of shoddy that the site doesn't make this clear and the text isn't tailored to the current user.

Comment: The badge doesn't give you level 1.  Staff intervention is required to get any level now, but you can have an existing superuser recommend you for consideration.